# Is there a way to verify that energy of a body is directly proportional to mass, without using the definition?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, mass, energy-conservation

How would I go about verifying that the energy a body possesses, is directly proportional to its mass to the first degree, without using the definition of work?

How could I show this fact without the prior knowledge that work is the sum of the product of the force and the distance travelled over a distance?

Comment: What makes you  think you  need to use the definition of work to show that the energy a body possesses is proportional to its mass, i.e., that energy is an extensive property?

Answer (score 1):

Energy of a body is not always proportional to mass. For example, electrostatic potential energy depends on the charge of the body and the electric field it is in. The mass doesn't influence electrostatic potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is an extensive property. Meaning its value varies with the mass of the system. Examples:

Kinetic energy of the  center of mass of a system in motion.

$$E_{KE}=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Gravitational potential energy height $h$ near surface of earth

$$E_{GPE}=mgh$$

Mass-energy equivalency

$$E=mc^2$$

Internal energy of a system (sum of microscopic kinetic and potential energies)

$$U=mu$$

where $U$ is the total internal energy of the system (kinetic + potential}, $u$ is the specific internal energy (internal energy per unit mass).

Hope this helps.